# R sum of column on a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
    a      b
1   A.1    1
2   A.2    2
3   A.3    1
5   B.1    2
6   B.2    2
7   B.3    1
```

I need to count for each letter (A and B here) the sum of the column b

```
    a   b
1   A   4
2   B   5
```

Comment: Create a new column without the replicate number .1 .2 .3 and then use ddply and summarise to sum the b column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is using `separate` from `tidyr` to separate the column 'a' based on the delimiter `.`, group using the new 'a' and get the `sum` of 'b'.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
separate(df1, a, into=c('a', 'a1')) %>% 
            group_by(a) %>% 
            summarise(b=sum(b))
#  a b
#1 A 4
#2 B 5
```

Or we can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`).  Use `sub` to remove the characters starting from `.`, followed by digits, use that as the grouping variable and get the `sum` of 'b'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,list(b=sum(b)) , by = .(a=sub('\\.\\d+$', '', a))]
#   a b
#1: A 4
#2: B 5
```

Or a similar option using the formula method of `aggregate` from `base R`.

```
aggregate(b~cbind(a=sub('\\.\\d+$', '', a)), df1, FUN=sum)
#   a b
# 1 A 4
# 2 B 5
```

Or using `sqldf`

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('select substr(a, 1, instr(a, ".")-1) as a1,
        sum(b) as b
        from df1 
        group by a1')
#   a1 b
#1  A 4
#2  B 5
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(a = c("A.1", "A.2", "A.3", "B.1", "B.2", "B.3"
), b = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L)), .Names = c("a", "b"),
 class =  "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: What do you think of `substr(dat$a,1,1)` as an alternative to the `sub` part?

Comment: @Jaap That is a good option, but I was thinking if the OP had groups such as `A1.1`, `B1.1` etc.